# Python socket send/recv gets gradually slower

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, send, recv

I'm using Python (3.8) for sharing files over my network.
This is done by a server/listener sending off chunks of the data (when asked for), and a client/recv:er that downloads the data.

All works well with the exception for one thing, the download speed always gradually but quickly becomes slower and slower, making a big impact on a 30MB file and an enormous impact on a 250MB file.

Here is an example of downloading a 25MB file:

```
query for data
Downloading File [1] at 1.42  kByte/sec
Downloading File [2] at 265.98  kByte/sec
Downloading File [3] at 530.53  kByte/sec
Downloading File [4] at 795.08  kByte/sec
Downloading File [5] at 1056.0  kByte/sec
Downloading File [6] at 1319.12  kByte/sec
Downloading File [7] at 1582.25  kByte/sec
Downloading File [8] at 1845.38  kByte/sec
Downloading File [9] at 2108.51  kByte/sec
Downloading File [10] at 2368.0  kByte/sec
Downloading File [11] at 2635.4  kByte/sec
Downloading File [12] at 2898.53  kByte/sec
Downloading File [13] at 3165.94  kByte/sec
Downloading File [14] at 3424.0  kByte/sec
Downloading File [15] at 3682.85  kByte/sec
Downloading File [16] at 3947.4  kByte/sec
Downloading File [17] at 4220.51  kByte/sec
Downloading File [18] at 4475.08  kByte/sec
Downloading File [19] at 4736.0  kByte/sec
Downloading File [20] at 5010.53  kByte/sec
Downloading File [21] at 5266.53  kByte/sec
Downloading File [22] at 5274.69  kByte/sec
Downloading File [23] at 5227.19  kByte/sec
Downloading File [24] at 5173.18  kByte/sec
Downloading File [25] at 5109.13  kByte/sec
Downloading File [26] at 5040.12  kByte/sec
Downloading File [27] at 4976.76  kByte/sec
Downloading File [28] at 4916.04  kByte/sec
Downloading File [29] at 4839.46  kByte/sec
Downloading File [30] at 4779.34  kByte/sec
Downloading File [31] at 4717.97  kByte/sec
Downloading File [32] at 4654.68  kByte/sec
Downloading File [33] at 4587.11  kByte/sec
Downloading File [34] at 4521.86  kByte/sec
Downloading File [35] at 4489.31  kByte/sec
Downloading File [36] at 4463.14  kByte/sec
Downloading File [37] at 4447.0  kByte/sec
Downloading File [38] at 4429.8  kByte/sec
Downloading File [39] at 4408.23  kByte/sec
Downloading File [40] at 4385.68  kByte/sec
Downloading File [41] at 4362.61  kByte/sec
Downloading File [42] at 4332.12  kByte/sec
Downloading File [43] at 4277.88  kByte/sec
Downloading File [44] at 4241.96  kByte/sec
Downloading File [45] at 4214.6  kByte/sec
Downloading File [46] at 4188.76  kByte/sec
Downloading File [47] at 4161.43  kByte/sec
Downloading File [48] at 4122.81  kByte/sec
Downloading File [49] at 4078.92  kByte/sec
Downloading File [50] at 4038.91  kByte/sec
Downloading File [51] at 3995.1  kByte/sec
Downloading File [52] at 3946.54  kByte/sec
Downloading File [53] at 3905.08  kByte/sec
Downloading File [54] at 3862.33  kByte/sec
Downloading File [55] at 3818.92  kByte/sec
Downloading File [56] at 3778.95  kByte/sec
Downloading File [57] at 3736.93  kByte/sec
Downloading File [58] at 3698.62  kByte/sec
Downloading File [59] at 3669.39  kByte/sec
Downloading File [60] at 3638.99  kByte/sec
Downloading File [61] at 3611.71  kByte/sec
Downloading File [62] at 3576.03  kByte/sec
Downloading File [63] at 3546.88  kByte/sec
Downloading File [64] at 3516.09  kByte/sec
Downloading File [65] at 3483.13  kByte/sec
Downloading File [66] at 3451.92  kByte/sec
Downloading File [67] at 3419.35  kByte/sec
Downloading File [68] at 3392.87  kByte/sec
Downloading File [69] at 3366.28  kByte/sec
Downloading File [70] at 3337.75  kByte/sec
Downloading File [71] at 3306.12  kByte/sec
Downloading File [72] at 3279.61  kByte/sec
Downloading File [73] at 3248.65  kByte/sec
Downloading File [74] at 3222.84  kByte/sec
Downloading File [75] at 3191.29  kByte/sec
Downloading File [76] at 3159.18  kByte/sec
Downloading File [77] at 3127.02  kByte/sec
Downloading File [78] at 3099.15  kByte/sec
Downloading File [79] at 3070.14  kByte/sec
Downloading File [80] at 3033.71  kByte/sec
Downloading File [81] at 3007.82  kByte/sec
Downloading File [82] at 2978.38  kByte/sec
Downloading File [83] at 2950.2  kByte/sec
Downloading File [84] at 2921.61  kByte/sec
Downloading File [85] at 2889.32  kByte/sec
Downloading File [86] at 2860.66  kByte/sec
Downloading File [87] at 2833.2  kByte/sec
Downloading File [88] at 2805.48  kByte/sec
Downloading File [89] at 2775.55  kByte/sec
Downloading File [90] at 2749.85  kByte/sec
Downloading File [91] at 2722.94  kByte/sec
Downloading File [92] at 2696.21  kByte/sec
Downloading File [93] at 2670.54  kByte/sec
Downloading File [94] at 2643.62  kByte/sec
Downloading File [95] at 2620.01  kByte/sec
Downloading File [96] at 2596.48  kByte/sec
Downloading File [97] at 2573.56  kByte/sec
Downloading File [98] at 2550.22  kByte/sec
Downloading File [99] at 2525.19  kByte/sec
Downloading File [100] at 2503.39  kByte/sec
Downloading File done [100%] in around 10seconds
```

As you can see, there is some initial work to get up to speed, which is normal (and for me acceptable), but then, at top speed around 5MB/s, it slowly drops without any specific reason.

For a bigger file, it just drops more and more until it literally crawls.

Interestingly, I can download 2 files at the same time without one interfering with another.
Say a 300MB file is going very slow at 0.4MB/s, another process will quickly jump up to 5MB/s (before starting to decline), so it seems it's the repeated send and/or recv that somehow slows down the socket.

The code is very straight forward, server sends data until all sent (with ack between chunks), recv just recv until a chunk has been downloaded then sends an ack, rinse and repeat until all is downloaded, and it works perfectly well.

Is there some magic I must perform on the sockets, like purging or something, or is Python not at ease with juggling lots of blocks of data (I send 32kb chunks so they sure do add up, but they are not indexed or stored, just added to the final result-data)?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Edit: Watered down functions of send & recv:

```
# Encodes a long long (8bytes) for the size of the rest of the data
# Then sends it by packages
# Sends msg as a sting, or opens the file if file 1= None and reads it and sends it off by chunks (So we won't fill up all the RAM)
def socket_secure_send(s, msg, file=None, extensive_logging=False):
    # As we all know, data sent over the internet might be split up, so send how many
    # bytes we'll try to push through here. An unsigned 8Byte integer should do the trick
    # hopefully for the foreseeable future:
    datasize = len(msg)
    lengthdata = pack('>Q', datasize)
    # Send a long long, little endian encoded information about the msg size
    try:
        # Send size of data to come
        s.send(lengthdata)

        # Send off the actual data
        
        # send by packets
        max_packet_size = get_configuration_value('server_send_package_size', 32768)
        data_size = len(msg)
        left_to_send = data_size
        sent = 0
        while left_to_send > 0:
            package_size = min(max_packet_size, left_to_send)

            # What? Didn't we already send the size of the data earlier?
            # We sure did, but this is so when someone is downloading your 1.5TB
            # it won't choke the OS:s small buffers
            # So here we'll use a smaller 32bits unsigned integer,
            # but beware, buffers can be small so don't use numbers too big!
            lengthdata = pack('>L', package_size)
            s.send(lengthdata)

            # Now send a chunk of the data
            data_to_send = msg[sent:sent+package_size]
            data_to_send_len = len(data_to_send)
            a = s.send(data_to_send)

            sent += package_size
            left_to_send -= package_size

            # And wait for the little Ack!
            ack = s.recv(1)  # todo check the ack = b'1' or something

        # Check if the data went through, other socket sends b'0' for success and others for error
        ack = s.recv(1)

        return ack == b'0'
    except socket.error:
        print("SSS There was a problem in socket_secure_send")

    return False


def read_chunk(s, chunk_size):
    chunk = b''
    while chunk_size > 0:
        part = s.recv(chunk_size)  # try to recv the missing data in the chunk
        if part is None:
            s.close()
            return

        chunk += part
        chunk_size -= len(part)

    return chunk

# Receive data in packages
# Recv:s in memory, or to a file if file != None
def socket_secure_recv(s, max_read_size, file=None, extensive_logging=False):
    # Recv the long long size data
    try:
        tmp = s.recv(8)
    except socket.error as e:
        err = e.args[0]
        if err == errno.EAGAIN or err == errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
            if extensive_logging:
                if err == errno.EAGAIN:
                    print('SSR no (size) data avaliable: errno.EAGAIN')
                if err == errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
                    print('SSR no (size) data avaliable: errno.EWOULDBLOCK')
            # No data available
            return None
        else:
            # Real error:
            print("SSR error: ", e)
            return None

    if len(tmp) != 8:
        return None

    (to_read, ) = unpack('>Q', tmp)

    data = b''
    read = to_read

    while read > 0:
        # Recv a chunk:
        chunk_size_data = s.recv(4)  # A 4 bit unsigned int for chunk size
        if len(chunk_size_data) != 4:
            return None

        (chunk_size,) = unpack('>L', chunk_size_data)

        # get a chunk:
        chunk = read_chunk(s, min(to_read, chunk_size))

        data = data + chunk

        # Send back ACK
        s.send(b'0')

        read = to_read - len(data)

    s.send(b'0')
    return data
```

Comment: You have added the `python` tag, but you have added no code to your question.

Comment: 32 kb chunks are no problem for python and there isn't any socket purging necessary. A client/server like this should run quite fast. So, its something in your implementation. If you are just reading / writing these blocks and then deleting them, all should be fine. Maybe these acks you've implemented, which includes some sort of command handshake I guess, could be the problem. But that's all just guessing. You could sprinkle some logging into your code that includes timestamps and write to a file. Later use that to profile where the time might be wasted.

Comment: @quamrana yes as it is a Python problem. This behaviour works perfectly well in C/C++ for example.

Comment: Its not a `python` problem until we see some code.

Comment: @tdelaney So a thousand data-adds of 32kb chunks should absolutely not impact Python performance? The hand shake is just wait for an ack byte when a chunk (of 32kb) has been received, and the logic works perfectly well :-/

Comment: So, what does the client do with each 32kb chunk when it arrives?

Comment: @quamrana It just slaps it onto a 'data' variable. I added the code at the end of the question.

Comment: I suspect that `data = data + chunk` is the problem because you are recreating all the data you have received so far, plus the next chunk. Do you know the total size before begin receiving?

Comment: Yep I sure do :-) So you propose a sort of prealloc + pasting into that memory?

Comment: You wouldn't keep 1000 data adds in memory before writing the file. But if this is a list of 32k strings, that's still only 32meg and change for overhead. Your disk should handle a 5MB data write rate, so that shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: You are better off keeping a list `data_list.append(data)` than `data = data + chunk` as that causes a copy of the entire accumulated data each time you do the `+`. But you don't want to hold 250M files in memory - but you seem to read the whole thing in the function. Other issues, `tmp = s.recv(8)` can end in tears because TCP might give you, say, 7 bytes then 1 byte. You could have a call that receives exactly what is asked for.

Comment: @tdelaney There sure are some corner cases in netcode (and it's not yet 'production code'), but I *do* at least check if len(tmp) != 8: ;-) and the code is supposed to handle all kind off mess-ups with retries, down nodes etc.so hopefully it's fairly robust! But duly noted in the todo list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list to buffer the data:

```py
data = []
read = to_read

while read > 0:
    # Recv a chunk:
    chunk_size_data = s.recv(4)  # A 4 bit unsigned int for chunk size
    if len(chunk_size_data) != 4:
        return None

    (chunk_size,) = unpack('>L', chunk_size_data)

    # get a chunk:
    chunk = read_chunk(s, min(to_read, chunk_size))

    data.append(chunk)

    # Send back ACK
    s.send(b'0')

    read = to_read - len(data)

s.send(b'0')
return b''.join(data)
```

The `getting slower` and `slaps it onto a 'data' variable` was tickling the old spidey-sense there.

Comment: Dude, you're the man, Thanks! ps. Extra credits for the b''.join(data), cheers and thanks again!